# When I put value in a Java Preference does it automatically flush?

Tags: java, preferences

I am using `java.util.prefs.Preferences` to store my application settings. Here is my sample code-

```
private static final Preferences mPreferences
        = Preferences.userRoot().node("lab_exam");

public static void setDefaultPath(java.nio.file.Path v)
{
    mPreferences.put(DEFAULT_PATH, v.toString());
    flush();
}

public static void flush()
{
    try {
        mPreferences.flush();
    }
    catch (BackingStoreException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppSettings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I am flushing the mPreference everytime I put a new value to ensure that data is saved sucessfully. Now my question is, does `Preference` automatically flush everytime I put something, or I am doing the correct thing?

Comment: Personally, I've never used `flush`, but that might be dependent on the underlying implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc of [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html):

> All of the methods that modify preferences data are permitted to operate asynchronously; they may return immediately, and changes will eventually propagate to the persistent backing store with an implementation-dependent delay. The flush method may be used to synchronously force updates to the backing store. Normal termination of the Java Virtual Machine will not result in the loss of pending updates -- an explicit flush invocation is not required upon termination to ensure that pending updates are made persistent.

So, use `flush()` if you want to guard against loss in case of **abnormal** termination of the VM, otherwise it's not needed. Be aware that flushing after every change **may** reduce performance, but in general I wouldn't be expecting you to update preferences often enough for that to be an issue.

Comment: So using flush is unnecessary. But one thing is bugging me. It says - "changes will eventually propagate to the persistent backing store with an implementation-dependent delay." How long this delay is? Should I consider it if I need the new data I stored within a short amount of time?

Comment: @SudiptoChandra The length of the delay is implementation-dependent. You could find out what the delay might be for a specific implementation, but writing implementation-dependent code is a generally not a good idea. If you want better guarantees as to when the data is flushed, then you could use `java.util.Timer` or `ScheduledExecutorService`.